# How can I read all the values in my Hashtable? (C#)

Tags: c#, hashtable

I have a hashtable and I have tried inputting all the values as either objects created from a class or as arrays. the arrays/objects are meant to be stand ins for cards and I want to use a random number generator to choose the keys of the hashtable and then to read out all the values associated to that key. Please can someone help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;


namespace CardGame
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static Hashtable monsters;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           monsters = new Hashtable();

            int[] mon1 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            int[] mon2 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            int[] mon3 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            int[] mon4 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            int[] mon5 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            int[] mon6 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            int[] mon7 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            int[] mon8 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            int[] mon9 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            int[] mon10 = new int[2] { 1, 4 };
            int[] mon11 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
            int[] mon12 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
            int[] mon13 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
            int[] mon14 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
            int[] mon15 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
            int[] mon16 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
            int[] mon17 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
            int[] mon18 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
            int[] mon19 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
            int[] mon20 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
            int[] mon21 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
            int[] mon22 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
            int[] mon23 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
            int[] mon24 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
            int[] mon25 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
            int[] mon26 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
            int[] mon27 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
            int[] mon28 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
            int[] mon29 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
            int[] mon30 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
            int[] mon31 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
            int[] mon32 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
            int[] mon33 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
            int[] mon34 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
            int[] mon35 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
            int[] mon36 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
            int[] mon37 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
            int[] mon38 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
            int[] mon39 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
            int[] mon40 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
            int[] mon41 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
            int[] mon42 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
            int[] mon43 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
            int[] mon44 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
            int[] mon45 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
            int[] mon46 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
            int[] mon47 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
            int[] mon48 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
            int[] mon49 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
            int[] mon50 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };

           
            monsters.Add(1, mon1);
            monsters.Add(2, mon2);
            monsters.Add(3, mon3);
            monsters.Add(4, mon4);
            monsters.Add(5, mon5);
            monsters.Add(6, mon6);
            monsters.Add(7, mon7);
            monsters.Add(8, mon8);
            monsters.Add(9, mon9);
            monsters.Add(10, mon10);
            monsters.Add(11, mon11);
            monsters.Add(12, mon12);
            monsters.Add(13, mon13);
            monsters.Add(14, mon14);
            monsters.Add(15, mon15);
            monsters.Add(16, mon16);
            monsters.Add(17, mon17);
            monsters.Add(18, mon18);
            monsters.Add(19, mon19);
            monsters.Add(20, mon20);
            monsters.Add(21, mon21);
            monsters.Add(22, mon22);
            monsters.Add(23, mon23);
            monsters.Add(24, mon24);
            monsters.Add(25, mon25);
            monsters.Add(26, mon26);
            monsters.Add(27, mon27);
            monsters.Add(28, mon28);
            monsters.Add(29, mon29);
            monsters.Add(30, mon30);
            monsters.Add(31, mon31);
            monsters.Add(32, mon32);
            monsters.Add(33, mon33);
            monsters.Add(34, mon34);
            monsters.Add(35, mon35);
            monsters.Add(36, mon36);
            monsters.Add(37, mon37);
            monsters.Add(38, mon38);
            monsters.Add(39, mon39);
            monsters.Add(40, mon40);
            monsters.Add(41, mon41);
            monsters.Add(42, mon42);
            monsters.Add(43, mon43);
            monsters.Add(44, mon44);
            monsters.Add(45, mon45);
            monsters.Add(46, mon46);
            monsters.Add(47, mon47);
            monsters.Add(48, mon48);
            monsters.Add(49, mon49);
            monsters.Add(50, mon50);

                        
            Random rand = new Random();

            
            var selection = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).Take(10).ToList();

            foreach (DictionaryEntry mons in monsters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"monster number {monsters.Keys}");
                foreach (var item in mons)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }

            }
```

I just cant seem to be able to access each value pairing from the hashtable.
P.S. there's a lot of commented out dead code at the bottom of things that I've tried.

Comment: Consider a `Dictionary<K, V>` instead of the antique HashTable class. Other than that, if you iterate you get a KeyVluePair and on that you can access .Key and .Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Hashtable` is not typed. The compiler doesn't know what types are in the table at runtime. So when you take things from the table, you have to specify the type you expect:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry mons in monsters)
{
    // Use mons.key, not monsters.key to access the number
    // Its type is object. Outputting it works, but
    // to actually work with it, you have to cast it back to int.
    Console.WriteLine($"monster number {mons.Key}");


    // To work with the int array inside the table, use
    // a cast 
    foreach (var item in mons.Value as int[])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

}
```

---

Instead of using outdated `Hashtable`, use a generic `Dictionary<>`, that supports specifying types at compile time:

```
internal class Program
{
    static Dictionary<int, int[]> monsters = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] mon1 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
        int[] mon2 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
        int[] mon3 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
        int[] mon4 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
        int[] mon5 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
        int[] mon6 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
        int[] mon7 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
        int[] mon8 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
        int[] mon9 = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
        int[] mon10 = new int[2] { 1, 4 };
        int[] mon11 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
        int[] mon12 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
        int[] mon13 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
        int[] mon14 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
        int[] mon15 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
        int[] mon16 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
        int[] mon17 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
        int[] mon18 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
        int[] mon19 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
        int[] mon20 = new int[2] { 2, 4 };
        int[] mon21 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
        int[] mon22 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
        int[] mon23 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
        int[] mon24 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
        int[] mon25 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
        int[] mon26 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
        int[] mon27 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
        int[] mon28 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
        int[] mon29 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
        int[] mon30 = new int[2] { 3, 6 };
        int[] mon31 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
        int[] mon32 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
        int[] mon33 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
        int[] mon34 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
        int[] mon35 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
        int[] mon36 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
        int[] mon37 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
        int[] mon38 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
        int[] mon39 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
        int[] mon40 = new int[2] { 4, 8 };
        int[] mon41 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
        int[] mon42 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
        int[] mon43 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
        int[] mon44 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
        int[] mon45 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
        int[] mon46 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
        int[] mon47 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
        int[] mon48 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
        int[] mon49 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };
        int[] mon50 = new int[2] { 5, 10 };


        monsters.Add(1, mon1);
        monsters.Add(2, mon2);
        monsters.Add(3, mon3);
        monsters.Add(4, mon4);
        monsters.Add(5, mon5);
        monsters.Add(6, mon6);
        monsters.Add(7, mon7);
        monsters.Add(8, mon8);
        monsters.Add(9, mon9);
        monsters.Add(10, mon10);
        monsters.Add(11, mon11);
        monsters.Add(12, mon12);
        monsters.Add(13, mon13);
        monsters.Add(14, mon14);
        monsters.Add(15, mon15);
        monsters.Add(16, mon16);
        monsters.Add(17, mon17);
        monsters.Add(18, mon18);
        monsters.Add(19, mon19);
        monsters.Add(20, mon20);
        monsters.Add(21, mon21);
        monsters.Add(22, mon22);
        monsters.Add(23, mon23);
        monsters.Add(24, mon24);
        monsters.Add(25, mon25);
        monsters.Add(26, mon26);
        monsters.Add(27, mon27);
        monsters.Add(28, mon28);
        monsters.Add(29, mon29);
        monsters.Add(30, mon30);
        monsters.Add(31, mon31);
        monsters.Add(32, mon32);
        monsters.Add(33, mon33);
        monsters.Add(34, mon34);
        monsters.Add(35, mon35);
        monsters.Add(36, mon36);
        monsters.Add(37, mon37);
        monsters.Add(38, mon38);
        monsters.Add(39, mon39);
        monsters.Add(40, mon40);
        monsters.Add(41, mon41);
        monsters.Add(42, mon42);
        monsters.Add(43, mon43);
        monsters.Add(44, mon44);
        monsters.Add(45, mon45);
        monsters.Add(46, mon46);
        monsters.Add(47, mon47);
        monsters.Add(48, mon48);
        monsters.Add(49, mon49);
        monsters.Add(50, mon50);

        // mons is type KeyValuePair<int, int[]>
        foreach (var mons in monsters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"monster number {mons.Key}");
            foreach (var item in mons.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

How to get the random selection from the dictionary:

```
Random rand = new Random();
var selection = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).Take(10).ToList();

foreach (var monId in selection)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"monster number {monId}");
    int[] monster = monsters[monId];
    
    foreach (var item in monster)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Or a shorter form if you need the random monsters in a list

```
Random rand = new Random();
var selection = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).Take(10).ToList();

var selectedMonsters = selection.Select(i => monsters[i]);

foreach (var monster in selectedMonsters)
{
    Console.WriteLine("monster");
    foreach (var item in monster)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all can I just say, thank you, you're a legend. Trust me to in the one iteration that I posted, write monsters.key (embarrassing). it seemed like such an easy fix, I'm annoyed that I couldn't come across the answer without bothering you, but thank you.
Out of interest are hashtables considered outdated now because unlike generic dictionaries you can't specify the types, or is there another reason?

Comment: Hashtables are still heavily used in languages that have no static typing (like PHP or JavaScript). The Hashtable class in C# is considered outdated with the introduction of generics in C# that allow the strongly typed Dictionary<> class.

Comment: So would it still be correct to use a hashtable if the values were all of a different type? if so how on earth would you print out all the differing values in that case? you can only use 1 as keyword right?

Comment: Putting objects of different types in the same list is a sign for a bad design in my opinion, but it might be necessary. If you do that, you can check the type at runtime using the `is` operator and then cast to the correct type. Newer c# versions allow "pattern matching" to do checking and casting in one statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74526849/pattern-matching-tuples-with-is-keyword/ for a sample

Comment: Or if all the values implement the same interface or derive from the same base class, you can have a list or dictionary using the interface or base type

Comment: Hot damn dude you pretty damn good at this coding malarkey. I'm finding it hard enough to learn the basics let alone keeping up with all the updates hahah. Thank you again for all your time and patience buddy, the world needs more Nineberries.