# Pattern matching tuples with "is" keyword?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a Blazor service which accepts any draggable object, boxed as `object`.  It could be a dragged user, or a classroom, or a scheduled item or almost anything else I might dream up later.

When the draggable is dropped into any component which supports dropping, the component needs to check if it's the right kind of object.  For example, the StudentList.razor component will only accept drops if they are `IdentityUser` or the duple `(IdentityUser, string)` where the string might be a role name or some other arbitrary info (TBD later):

```
    <div class="class-students-drop" @ondrop="_=>HandleStudentDrop()">
       . . .
    </div>
    @code {
        async Task HandleStudentDrop()
        {
            if (DM.GetItem() is IdentityUser Person)
            {           
                // Do generic user thing (works fine)
             
            } 
            if (DM.GetItem() is (IdentityUser person,string  role) RolePerson)
            {
                // Do thing based on specified role
                // Error (active)   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Deconstruct' and no accessible extension method 'Deconstruct' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found
            }
        }
    }
```

**I can pattern-check a class instance like `IdentityUser`, but I can't figure out how to check if the boxed object fits a particular duple form.**

**My question: what's the right syntax (if any) to check the signature of a duple using the 'is' keyword?**

I've seen examples with pattern-matching duples with values using `switch`, but I really just want to check if the boxed object is an `(IdentityUser, string) duple.

My references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct

Comment: What is `DM.GetItem() ` - and why aren't you using client-side `Event` objects?

Comment: Please don't worry about that.  It just returns the currently dragged `object`.  I just want to know how to pattern-check a boxed duple.

Comment: Try `if( DM.GetItem() is ValueTuple<IdentityUser,String> rolePerson )` - though you'll lose member names: so use `Item1` and `Item2` respectively.

Comment: Nice.  I tried a bunch of random things, including ValueTuple but I had it in parantheses.

Comment: Hang on, posting an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the identifier after the tuple type definition:

```
private object Test()
{
    return (new IdentityUser("Me"), "Test");
}

object o = Test();

if(o is (IdentityUser user, string role))
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.UserName + " " + role);
}
```

Comment: ...wow, dang. You win, sir!

Comment: It triggers me slightly not to be able to name the matched object, but it looks like this is what I was looking for.  ty.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 With the introduction of the `record` in C#, it feels much cleaner to use records for such  purposes than using tuples, IMHO.

Comment: @NineBerry `record struct` now

Comment: @NineBerry How would a record improve on your sample?

Comment: I just wanted to add for the record that this will match literals, too.  My entire drop method is now: `if(DM.GetItem() is (IdentityUser User, "student")) { if(!Class.Students.Contains(User)) Class.Students.Add(User); }`

Answer (score 2):

The quick-and-dirty approach should work:

```
if( DM.GetItem() is ValueTuple<IdentityUser,String> rolePerson )
{
    
}
```

...though you'll lose member names: so use `Item1` and `Item2` respectively.

---

Another (better) approach is to use an extension method over `Object`:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Boolean IsTuple<TTuple>( this Object obj, [NotNullWhen(true)] out TTuple? tuple )
        where TTuple : struct, ITuple
    {
        if( obj is TTuple ok )
        {
            tuple = ok;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            tuple = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
void Main()
{
    ( Int32 x, String y ) tuple = ( 123, "abc" );
    Object? obj = tuple;
    
    if( obj.IsTuple( out ( Int32 x, Single y )? notThis ) )
    {
        notThis.Dump( "Not this" );
    }
    else if( obj.IsTuple( out ( Int32 x, String y )? thisWorks ) )
    {
        thisWorks.Dump( "OK" );
    }
    else
    {
        "".Dump( "Nor this either." );
    }
}
```

Screenshot proof it works:

[image]

In your case, it'd be:

```
async Task HandleStudentDrop()
{
    if (DM.GetItem() is IdentityUser Person)
    {           
        // Do generic user thing (works fine)
             
    } 
    else if (DM.GetItem().IsTuple( out ( IdentityUser person, String role )? ok ) )
    {
        <p><b>Name:</b> @( ok.Value.person.Name )</p>
        <p><b>Role:</b> @( ok.Value.role )</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's what I currently have after your previous post:  `var item = DM.GetItem(); if (item is ValueTuple<IdentityUser,String>) {var RolePerson= ((IdentityUser user, string role)) item; }`  I think this should give me the named variables, but pattern-matching ValueType and then casting to the same duple feels too redundant.  I really want to match and assign the duple, but maybe C# doesn't allow this?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 why not just use my `IsTuple` extension I posted?

Comment: I like your answer very much-- it's quite clever, and I can learn something from it for later reference.  However, my goal is to see how far I can go with the `is` keyword.  It really feels to me like it should be possible to pattern-check and deconstruct in one line, and working around it is bugging me. :)